webdriver.io remote detect chrome restart
I am using webdriver.io with devtools protocol to connect to a chromium process that I started with --remote-debugging-port=9222 using:
    this.browser = await remote({
      logLevel: 'trace',
      automationProtocol: 'devtools',
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
          debuggerAddress: 'localhost:9222'
        }
      }
    })

It's working well but in some cases the chromium process exits and restarts which presumably breaks the remote debug port connection.  I would like to detect this case and re-initialize the browser connection.  Is it possible?  browser.status() does not show any change, only way I know of is to try a function and wait for it to timeout (5 minutes by default).
